# Regular Expression for Starts with lowercase letter, ends with lowercase letter or digit and middle is lowercase letters, digits, and underscore

Tags: regex

This is the expression I have: `^[a-z][a-z0-9_]+[a-z0-9]$`

Right now it doesn't match anything. How do I make it match `ems_agencies` but not `ems_agencies_` ?

Comment: Your current regex works just fine. How are you using it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specific dialect of regular expressions you are using, and also add it to the question’s tag set. For example, you might add a tag for any of grep, javascript, java, perl, python, ruby, and many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it "doesn't match anything", then it's possible that you're using the wrong dialect of regular expression.  The `+` is an element of ERE, and does not work in BRE.  If you're using this with the `grep` command, for example, then you need to run it as `egrep` or use the `-E` option.

```
$ printf 'ems_agencies\nems_agencies_\n' | egrep '^[a-z][a-z0-9_]+[a-z0-9]$'
ems_agencies
$ printf 'ems_agencies\nems_agencies_\n' |  grep '^[a-z][a-z0-9_]+[a-z0-9]$'
$
```

If you tell us the environment in which you're using this regular expression, it may help narrow down the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in some cases to convert an ERE into a BRE.  For instance, instead of writing `[a-z0-9]+`, you can write `[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]*`.  This will work universally in all regular expression implementations at the expense of readability.

```
printf "ems_agencies\nems_agencies_\n" | grep '^[a-z][a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9]$'
ems_agencies
```

Answer (score -1):

Your expression works fine. See here: http://regex101.com/r/gM1zM2

For future reference: `[0-9]` is the same as `\d` and `[a-z0-9_]` is equal to `\w`. Keep in mind though that `\w` is *case insensitive*

Comment: Note that some JS implementations may not include shortcuts like `\d` and `\w`, and they are not always included consistently.  For example, `\w` is *supposed* to be an alias for the character class `[[:alnum:]]`, so it *should not* include an underscore.  My preference is generally to write what you mean without such short-cuts.

Comment: @ghoti You are incorrect. According to [Annex C on Compatibility Properties, in UTS #18, Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties), `\w` is supposed to be an alias for `[\p{alpha}\p{gc=Mark}\p{digit}\p{gc=Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`, and you will note that U+005F LOW LINE is indeed part of the `gc=Connector_Punctuation` class.  Thus, underscore is indeed supposed to be part of `\w`; QED.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually, I think you've just proven that I *am* correct, since that documentation is precisely at odds with the man page for GNU `grep`, which states: *The symbol \w is a synonym for `[[:alnum:]]` and \W is a synonym for `[^[:alnum:]]`*.  The web-based documentation for GNU grep states that it matches `[_[:alnum:]]` which is also different from the unicode version.  As far as I can tell, `\w` isn't even included in older (non-GNU) implementations of grep. The fact that different environments implement this differently is sufficient reason never to use it.

Comment: @ghoti Primitive tools like `grep` do not lend themselves to working in a modern text-processing environment, which is necessarily Unicode-based. The original poster did not specify what tool or language he’s using, so all bets are off. Yes, you should know what your tool does with these, but you’re a Luddite if you don’t use shortcuts: I’d like to see how you writing things to handle a wider character set. Shortcuts like `\w`, `\d`, `\s` have been around for the at least 25 years, and are a lot more readable than the long version give above by the Unicode Standard. Just know what they do.

Comment: @tchrist - I guess I'm a Luddite for still using command line tools and reading man pages.  Sure, know your environment and write for it.  Always good advice.  But regular expressions have never been implemented perfectly.  JavaScript wasn't around 25 years ago, but it's in widespread use now, and includes shortcuts like `\w` but doesn't include POSIX character classes.  Without knowing the target environment, a StackOverflow answer should either *work everywhere* or *document its limitations*.

Comment: @tchrist - Exactly.  Our audience is the entire StackOverflow user base.  All the more reason to avoid grandstanding and do the best job we possibly can to make our answers applicable to the real world.